# HQL to access the subclass object of @manytoOne fields

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql, hibernate-mapping

I have scenario in which below is the superclass:-

```
abstract class  Container
{
    Long id;
    FieldParent parent;
}

class SubContainer extends Container
{
    Long extid;
}

abstract class FieldParent
{
    Long fid;
    String name;
}

class SubField  extends FieldParent
{
    String typeOfSub;
}
```

I am using Table per subclass strategy using a discriminator
Below is hbm mapping of Container:-

```
<class name="Container" table="Container">
    <id name="id" type="long" column="ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
     <many-to-one name="parent"
                     class="FieldParent"
                     cascade="none"
                     column="FieldParentID"/>
    <discriminator column="TYPE"/>
    ....
    <subclass name="SubContainer"
                  discriminator-value="S"
                  lazy="true">
          <property name="extid"  type="long"  column="extid" not-null="true"/>
    </subclass>
</class>
```

Below is hbm mapping of FieldParent:-

```
   <class name="FieldParent" table="FieldParent">
        <id name="fid" type="long" column="FID">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name"  type="java.lang.String"  column="name" not-null="true"/>
        <discriminator column="TYPE_Parent"/>
        ....
        <subclass name="SubField"
                      discriminator-value="F"
                      lazy="true">
            <property name="typeOfSub"  type="java.lang.String"  column="typeOfSub" not-null="true"/>
        </subclass>
    </class>
```

Now I have the object of SubContainer and I am query based on 'typeOfSub' value.
I tried using below query

```
getHibernateTemplate().find(
        "from " + SubContainer.class.getName()
                + " subContainer where subContainer.extid = ? and subContainer.parent.typeOfSub=? ",
        new Object[]{new Long(id), "sampeTypeoFSub"});
```

but faced 'org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred '.
I understand I cant be just assume that it will be SubField object so cant access the fields but I need to figuure out the way for. I am not sure if we can cast in HQL?
I tried searching for the resolution but dint find any similar question.

Below is the stacktrace :

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "FieldParent_3_"."typeOfSub": invalid identifier
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1281) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
>   at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:342) [:6.0.0.Final]

Updated stack trace for exception.Also just FYI, FieldParent has 3 subclasses one of which is SubField .

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "FieldParent1_3_"."typeOfSub": invalid identifier

```
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1281) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:342) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208) [:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953) [:3.6.10.Final]
```

Comment: Post the complete StackTrace !

Comment: @NeerajJain there is really not much there still updated the question..Hope that helps

Comment: Please check you dont have getter of FieldParent.typeOfSub

Comment: @xrcwrn I do have it I have not put that here but I have it in code

Answer (score 1):

The `typeOfSub` property is in the `SubField` class and the `Container` has a many-to-one association to a `FieldParent` instead.

1. You either move the property into `FieldParent`
2. You filter the association to the subclass type:

   ```
   select subContainer
   from SubContainer subContainer
   where 
       subContainer.parent.class = my.package.SubField
       subContainer.extid = ? and 
       subContainer.parent.typeOfSub=?
   ```

Comment: Hi Vlad, can you please take a look at my post here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894928/how-to-join-2-entities-based-on-not-condition

Comment: Hi @VladMihalcea thanks a lot.. I cant use option 1 . But I tried option 2. with an assumption that you meant subContainer.parent.class = my.package.SubField . It gives me exception **java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "FieldParent 1_3_"."typeOfSub": invalid identifier** , I updated stacktrace in my question.. Do you think I can avoid option one and still access SubField objects property in HQL.

Answer (score -1):

I tried @VladMihalcea answers but sadly dint work. After digging more into the issue  I dont think its possible to do access subclasses elements in HQL.
So here's what I did as workaround  and worked for me.

```
getHibernateTemplate().find("select subCont from " +SubContainer.class.getName()+" subCont, " + SubField.class.getName() +" subField "
where subCont.extid = ? and subField.typeOfSub=? and subCont.parent.fid=subField.fid",
        new Object[]{new Long(id), "sampeTypeoFSub"});
```

Basically joing the tables. Kind of similar to inner join.